# Aptana 3.0 "click off" mark occurrences for PHP

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I'm loving Aptana Studio 3, but one thing bugs me: the mark occurrences in PHP! I like being able to click the variable and find all occurrences of it, but I want to click off when I'm done. Right now it finds the occurrences, but then when I click on some blank area, the occurrence is still marked.

Is there any way to make it so that it cancels the mark when the cursor's off the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Studio 'behave' like other Eclipse-based products with that feature (e.g. JDT etc.). The idea is to have the selection sticky until a new valid PHP element is detected.

You can add a feature request for this at http://aptana.com/r/apbugs and maybe a preference for that can be added.

Right now there is no real workaround for this. The only way to get rid of the occurrences markers is to turn it off and back on (Alt+Shift+O), but it's not so great :)

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping I could pull off some AutoIt magic at worst, but it seems not.

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4511 is the ticket, for any interested in its progress